# strongloop loopback: how to add remote method to loopback-component-storage Container

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to add a new REST API method to the loopback-component-storage for downloading all photos from a Container. (see [Strongloop loopback-storage-service: how to use StorageService.downloadStream() to download a ZIP of all photos in container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137729/strongloop-loopback-storage-service-how-to-download-a-zip-of-all-photos-in-cont/29139189#29139189))

The following code seems to work, but I'd like to know how to load the storage-handler, `handler`, and filesystem provider, `factory`, correctly within the strongloop framework. Also, I shouldn't have to copy the data in `datasources.json`

Any suggestions?

```
// http://localhost/api/containers/container1/downloadContainer/IMG_0799.PNG

// file: ./server/models/container.js
loopback_component_storage_path = "../../node_modules/loopback-component-storage/lib/";

datasources_json_storage = {
  "name": "storage",
  "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
  "provider": "filesystem",
  "root": "svc/storage",
  "_options": {
    "getFileName": "",
    "allowedContentTypes": "",
    "maxFileSize": "",
    "acl": ""
  }
};

handler = require(loopback_component_storage_path + './storage-handler');

factory = require(loopback_component_storage_path + './factory');

module.exports = function(Container) {
  Container.downloadContainer = function(container, files, res, ctx, cb) {
    var provider;
    provider = factory.createClient(datasources_json_storage);
    return handler.download(provider, null, res, container, files, cb);
  };
  Container.remoteMethod('downloadContainer', {
    shared: true,
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'container', type: 'string', 'http': {source: 'path'}},
      {arg: 'files', type: 'string', 'http': {source: 'path'}},
      {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}}
    ],
    returns: [],
    http: {
      verb: 'get',
      path: '/:container/downloadContainer/:files'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the `container.js` model file, you can easily access the StorageService you have defined in `datasources.json`. Once you have that, you can just call its `download()` method. No need to instantiate (redundantly and with every request) `factory` or `handler` in your code.

```
service = Container.app.dataSources.{SourceName}.connector
service.download(container, file, res, cb)
```