# Trying to correctly download zip file using express

Tags: node.js, http, express, https

I want to download a zip file using express, the point here is that by when I am trying to download txt file it is working correctly it downloads what I want. But in case of .zip format it downloads an empty file with the exact name what I want but in txt format.

```
static getFile(req, res) {
        fileManager.getfile(req, (r) => {
            if (!r.success) {
                return res.status(r.code).send(r);
            }

            return res.download(r.result.zipFileDirName + r.result.zipFileName);
                   });
    }

this is the get file functuion
    getFile(req, callback) {
        let validation = reportValidator.validateGetFile(req);
        if (!validation.success) {
            return callback(validation);
        }
        let findQuery = validation.result.query;
        Something.find(findQuery).exec((err, gh) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(`Error while finding somehting, err : ${err}`);
                return callback({success: false, code: 500, err: err});
            }
            let dirName = parentDir + req.query.accountId + '_' + req.query.dateFrom + '_' + req.query.dateTo + '/';
            let archive = archiver('zip', {
                gzip: true,
                zlib: { level: 9 }
            });
            archive.on('error', (err) => {
                logger.error(err);
                return callback({success: false, code: 500, err: err});
            });

            archive.on('end', () => {
                console.log('Archive wrote %d bytes', archive.pointer());
            });

            let zipFileName = req.query.accountId + '_' + req.query.dateFrom + '_' + req.query.dateTo + '.zip';
            let zipFile = fs.createWriteStream(dirName + zipFileName);
            archive.pipe(zipFile);

            async.each(gh,
                (item, next) => {
                let fileName = item.handId + '_' + Date.now() + '.mat';
                    this.makeReportingFile(dirName, fileName, item.gameInfo, r => {
                        if (!r.success) {
                            return next(err);
                        }
                        archive.file(r.result.file, {name: item.handId + '.mat'});
                        next(null, 'OK');
                    });
                },
                (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error(JSON.stringify(err));
                        return callback({success: false, code: 500, err: err});
                    }
                    archive.finalize();this on end
                    return callback({success: true, code: 200, result: {message: "OK", zipFileDirName: dirName, zipFileName: zipFileName}});
                });
        });
    }
```

I have provided additional info

Comment: Try to set the `content-type` header to `application/zip` :  `res.setHeaders('Content-Type', 'application/zip').download(...)`

Comment: @Fefux does not help :(

Comment: I think you should stream your zip file

Comment: @HaneTV how ? can u please provide an example ?

Comment: I think you could use something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107303/dynamically-create-and-stream-zip-to-client

Comment: @HaneTV I have tried that, does not help, I have provided additional code

Comment: I have found a solution: return callback of success true in case when the file is written already. so output,on('close')